# Delphi.Stretch Control (anchors:l,r,t and align:alNone) if one Control is Invisible

Tags: delphi, controls, anchor, alignment

Did anybody do this?

If I have 2 components on a form, 1-st is invisible, 2-d (which has anchors:left,right,top and align:alNone) must fill space of invisible control. For example, if you have uTorrent try to hide list of categories then listview will immediately fill free space.

How to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the `Align` property of controls. Group them in `TPanel` controls, if necessary. If you are using a new version of Delphi, you can play with `Margin` and `AlignWithMargin` properties to get everything right. As a last resort, you can always adjust positions manually using code.

Comment: @Andreas, that sounds like an answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

Just set `Align` of second control to `alClient` and it will do just that (filling the available space). You do not need to set the `Anchors` in this case.

Comment: See what is happening. I have TreeView (left) and PageControl (Right and alClient). I have ListView and other controls (so I can not do them alClient) on PageControl. If I do Visible:=false for TreeView then PageControl (with all other control on it) goes left on position of TreeView but ListView (wich is on PageControl) is not stretched, I have free space (width of TreeView) on the right. How to fix it I have result like in uTorrent?

Comment: I don't know uTorrent but why can't you set the list view's alignment to `alClient`. What's the alignment of the other controls on the page control`?